# Old time travel series with older self helping younger self

Tags: story-identification

I'm currently looking for an old series (saw 1 or 2 episodes some 10-20 years ago). I'm not sure if it’s a live action series or an anime though.

What I remember is:

- A boy (12-16?) goes to school in the modern days and has a female friend (or possibly girlfriend)
- They go to a graveyard? in the first episode and suddenly get attacked with the attacker trying to kill HER.

What I'm else remembering is:

- Someone is helping them repeatedly. A grownup.....his older self who wants to save her (which he failed to do so previously).
- The villain who tries to kill her is actually another version of his older self trying to make sure that he gains all the power he did (following the timeline where she was killed).

In the end the villain is defeated and deleted from history and the older self goes home. She....got absolutely smitten by the older self and promised herself to wait until "he" grows to that age as he is bound to look the same then (as it’s just his older self).

Comment: I think this one has been asked before, but I don't know an answer.

Comment: @EmsleyWyatt I thought so too...but didn't find anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like the anime [Noein: To Your Other Self](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noein:_To_Your_Other_Self).

[image: A promotional poster (in Japanese) for Noein. Source: Wikipedia]

> Fifteen years in the future, a violent pan-dimensional war is taking place between the two dominant "time-spaces" of the universe: La'cryma (a possible future of our own world) and Shangri-La (another possible dimension fifteen years after ours intent on the destruction of all space and time).
>
> In one possible present, twelve-year-old Haruka and her friend Yū Gotō are contemplating running away from home when they meet... Karasu, who is a possible Yū from the future. Karasu vows to protect her rather than sacrifice her for his home dimension. Haruka is [also] targeted by the mysterious Noein, the entity behind Shangri'la who is intent on bringing her into his timespace to end all universes.

Having watched the anime, I can also confirm that the first episode features the main girl being attacked in a graveyard and saved by the boy's future self, and also that

> the villain, Noein, is yet another alternate future version of Yu, driven to madness after watching her die in his past.